# cannot import name '_ParamsValidationMixin' from 'imblearn.base'

Tags: smote

I've re-installed the latest `scikit-learn` and `imbalanced-learn`. I've also checked all other libraries to make sure they are compatible with `imbalanced-learn`. But I keep getting the error below when I try to import `imblearn`. Can somebody tell me why it's not working, please?

**Code:**

```
import imblearn
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

**Error Message:**

```
cannot import name '_ParamsValidationMixin' from 'imblearn.base
```